# Best way for show "small popup" on input type text

Tags: html, css

I need to show some informations in small popup when I put the mouse on an input type text.

For the moment I'm using title balise like this: http://jsfiddle.net/q8Lp0nLo/

```
<input type="text" size="5"><div>The text to show</div>

div{
    display:inline-block;
    visibility:hidden;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#E5E5F0; color:black;
}
input[type="text"]:hover~ div{visibility:visible}
```

It works fine on chrome but not on IE. If I fill completely the input, the popup doesn't appear or appears and hides few seconds later.

What is the best way for make this? : DONE

New question : How can i show the popup next to the position of the mouse (I don't need to moove the popup meanwhile the mouse moving too, just show it one time at the 1st position).

Actual code: http://jsfiddle.net/q8Lp0nLo/

Like this one but with the popup :http://jsfiddle.net/BaDCe/

Thanks

Comment: search for `tooltip` and `html/css` in google.. you will find a lot of information about that

Comment: use bootrstap popover or tooltip

Comment: http://tooltipsy.com/samples

Comment: Thanks, i have udpate my question :)

Answer (score 3):

Try this one :

```css
/* tooltip */


.tool-tip{
 color: #fff;
 background-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .7);
 text-shadow: none;
 font-size: .8em;
 visibility: hidden;
 -webkit-border-radius: 7px; 
 -moz-border-radius: 7px; 
 -o-border-radius: 7px; 
 border-radius: 7px; 
 text-align: center; 
 opacity: 0;
 z-index: 999;
 padding: 3px 8px; 
 position: absolute;
 cursor: default;
 -webkit-transition: all 240ms ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 240ms ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 240ms ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 240ms ease-in-out;
 transition: all 240ms ease-in-out; 
}

.tool-tip,
.tool-tip.top{
 top: auto;
 bottom: 114%;
 left: 50%;  
}

.tool-tip.top:after,
.tool-tip:after{
 position: absolute;
 bottom: -12px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -7px;
 content: ' ';
 height: 0px;
 width: 0px;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .7); 
}

/* default heights, width and margin w/o Javscript */

.tool-tip,
.tool-tip.top{
 width: 80px;
 height: 22px;
 margin-left: -43px;
}

/* tool tip position right */

.tool-tip.right{
 top: 50%;
 right: auto;
 left: 106%;
 margin-top: -15px;
 margin-right: auto; 
 margin-left: auto;
}

.tool-tip.right:after{
 left: -5px;
 top: 50%; 
 margin-top: -6px;
 bottom: auto;
 border-top-color: transparent; 
    border-right-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .7); 
}

/* tool tip position left */

.tool-tip.left{
 top: 50%;
 left: auto;
 right: 105%;
 margin-top: -15px; 
 margin-left: auto; 
}

.tool-tip.left:after{
 left: auto;
 right: -12px;
 top: 50%;
 margin-top: -6px;
 bottom: auto;
 border-top-color: transparent; 
    border-left-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .7); 
}

/* tool tip position bottom */

.tool-tip.bottom{
 top: 115%;
 bottom: auto;
 left: 50%;
 margin-bottom: auto; 
}

.tool-tip.bottom:after{
 position: absolute;
 top: -12px;
 left: 50%;
 margin-left: -7px;
 content: ' ';
 height: 0px;
 width: 0px;
 border: 6px solid transparent;
    border-top-color: transparent; 
    border-bottom-color: rgba( 0, 0, 0, .6); 
}

/* tooltip on focus left and right */

.on-focus .tool-tip.left,
.on-focus .tool-tip.right{
 margin-top: -19px;
}

/* on hover of element containing tooltip default*/

*:not(.on-focus):hover > .tool-tip,
.on-focus input:focus + .tool-tip{
 visibility: visible;
 opacity: 1;
 -webkit-transition: all 240ms ease-in-out;
 -moz-transition: all 240ms ease-in-out;
 -ms-transition: all 240ms ease-in-out;
 -o-transition: all 240ms ease-in-out;
 transition: all 240ms ease-in-out;  
}


/* tool tip slide out */

*:not(.on-focus) > .tool-tip.slideIn,
.on-focus > .tool-tip{
 display: block;
}

.on-focus > .tool-tip.slideIn{
 z-index: -1;
}

.on-focus > input:focus + .tool-tip.slideIn{
 z-index: 1;
}

/* bottom slideIn */

*:not(.on-focus) > .tool-tip.slideIn.bottom,
.on-focus > .tool-tip.slideIn.bottom{
 top: 50%; 
}

*:not(.on-focus):hover > .tool-tip.slideIn.bottom,
.on-focus > input:focus + .tool-tip.slideIn.bottom{
 top: 115%;
} 

.on-focus > input:focus + .tool-tip.slideIn.bottom{
 top: 100%;
}

/* top slideIn */

*:not(.on-focus) > .tool-tip.slideIn,
*:not(.on-focus) > .tool-tip.slideIn.top,
.on-focus > .tool-tip.slideIn,
.on-focus > .tool-tip.slideIn.top{
 bottom: 50%;
}

*:not(.on-focus):hover > .tool-tip.slideIn,
*:not(.on-focus):hover > .tool-tip.slideIn.top,
.on-focus > input:focus + .tool-tip.slideIn,
.on-focus > input:focus + .tool-tip.slideIn.top{
 bottom: 110%;
} 

/* left slideIn */

*:not(.on-focus) > .tool-tip.slideIn.left,
.on-focus > .tool-tip.slideIn.left{
 right: 50%; 
}

*:not(.on-focus):hover > .tool-tip.slideIn.left,
.on-focus > input:focus + .tool-tip.slideIn.left{
 right: 105%;  
}

/* right slideIn */

*:not(.on-focus) > .tool-tip.slideIn.right,
.on-focus > .tool-tip.slideIn.right{
 left: 50%;  
}

*:not(.on-focus):hover > .tool-tip.slideIn.right,
.on-focus > input:focus + .tool-tip.slideIn.right{
 left: 105%;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 550px; margin: 0px auto;">
  <div style="clear:both;padding:20px;"></div>
  <div class="on-focus clearfix" style="position: relative; padding: 0px; margin: 10px auto; display: table; float: left">
   <input type="text" value="" name="try" placeholder="Tooltip right on focus" />
   <div class="tool-tip slideIn right">Tool Tip</div>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="on-focus clearfix" style="position: relative; padding: 0px; margin: 10px auto; display: table; float: left">
   <input type="text" value="" name="try" placeholder="Tooltip left on focus" />
   <div class="tool-tip slideIn left">Tool Tip</div>
  </div>  

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="on-focus clearfix" style="position: relative; padding: 0px; margin: 10px auto; display: table; float: left">
   <input type="text" value="" name="try" placeholder="Tooltip Top on focus" />
   <div class="tool-tip  slideIn">Tool Tip</div>
  </div>

  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <div class="on-focus clearfix" style="position: relative; padding: 0px; margin: 10px auto; display: table; float: left">
   <input type="text" value="" name="try" placeholder="Tooltip Bottom on focus" />
   <div class="tool-tip bottom  slideIn ">Tool Tip</div>
  </div> 
 </div>
```

source: http://cssdeck.com/labs/tooltipscss3

Answer (score 2):

instead of title you can use a div element.
like this:

```css
div{
    display:inline-block;
    visibility:hidden;
}
input[type="text"]:focus~ div{visibility:visible}
```

```html
<input type="text" size="5"><div>balblabla</div>
```

**note:** If code doesn't work i can prepare the whole recipe in jsfiddle :) happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways in which we can solve this problem. 
Following solution uses `jquery`:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  $("#sample").focusout(function() {
    $("#tip").addClass("hidden");
    })
  .focusin(function () {
    $("#tip").removeClass("hidden");
   });

});
```

```css
.hidden {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#tip {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding:2px;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="sample" /> <div id="tip" class="hidden">Some Useful Message</div>
```